# xdotool, click and hold and move the mouse

Tags: linux, mouse, google-maps, xdotools

I want to automate a task, I need to scroll a Google like map interface, what I essentially do normally is:

1. Click an a spot
2. Hold the clicking
3. Move the mouse relatively 100 pixels left
4. Stop holding
5. Wait a little, return to 1

However, I tried `$ xdotool click 1 mousemove_relative 0 100` but it did not help, it seems it does not hold it. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Pure xdotool version

Let's say your spot is 500 500

```
xdotool mousemove 500 500
xdotool mousedown 1
xdotool mousemove_relative 0 100
xdotool mouseup 1
sleep 1
```

You could also condense it to only one line, if you wanted to:

```
xdotool mousemove 500 500 mousedown 1 mousemove_relative 0 100 mouseup 1 sleep 1
```

Comment: The mouse movement code works, but the `xdotool keydown Pointer_Button1` command doesn't do any clicks.

Comment: The command seems to have changed to: xdotool mousedown 1 (instead of Pointer_Button1)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [xnee](http://www.gnu.org/software/xnee/) to record your mouse action and replay it later when needed.

There's a gui for it called `gnee`. I didn't have very good results with it last time i tried but that was a long time ago, things might have changed since then.

Here's what i used for the recording:

```
$ sleep 2 ; xmessage ready ; sleep 1 ; cnee --record --mouse --keyboard -o cnee.data
```

This lets you move around and prepare things before starting. Click `ok` when you're ready, wait 1s and do your action. <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> when you're done.

Then you can replay it with:

```
$cnee --replay -f cnee.data -v -e /dev/null -ns
```

You can even replay it faster than the original (!)

```
$cnee --replay --speed-percent 40  -f cnee.data -v -e /dev/null -ns
```

You'll probably have to edit out the end of `cnee.data` to get rid of what you did in between your action and the <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hold down, wait 1 second, move to coordinate 0 0, wait another second, and hold up, try this:

```
xdotool mousedown 1 sleep 1 mousemove 0 0 sleep 1 mouseup 1
```